# Function that partitions a list haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of numbers eg `[3,1,3]` using this list of numbers I want to partition another list. For example `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` would become `[[1,2,3],[4],[5,6,7]]` using the `[3,1,3]` list. I know there is a function in the split package called `chunksOf` that could do this but I want to be able to do this without it. Would `splitAt` be useful in this situation?If so, how could I implement it?

Comment: “Would `splitAt` be useful in this situation?” – Yes, it would. Have you tried using it?

Comment: I have attempted it but it only makes the first partition

Comment: Right. Then you use it again to make the second partition. Then again to make the third partition. Try it manually in GHCi, then you'll spot the pattern and can make a recursive definition out of it. If you can't get that to work, put your code in the question and we'll help you with this.

Comment: How am I able to make future partitions if the output of the first partition is ([a],[a]) and splitAt expects an input of [a]?

Comment: How about ``case someTupleThingy of (a,b) -> useBoth a `andAlso` b``?

Comment: `chunksOf` *cannot* do this. Can you see why?

Comment: voting to close due to no attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call this function `chunkify`. This function takes two arguments, the list of values and the list of the lengths of the chunks, so it has the signature

```
chunkify:: [a] -> [Int] -> [[a]]
```

Furthermore if the first list or the second list is empty, the result must be empty too:

```
chunkify [] _ = []
chunkify _ [] = []
```

Now you already found `splitAt` which does what you want but only once. So if we have a list `x` and some length `l` we can split off a chunk with

```
(chunk, remainder) = splitAt l x
```

But now we need to make a list of these and repeat this with the `remainder`.
One way of doing so would be recursively defining a list:

```
chunkify x (l:ls) = chunk: chunkify remainder ls
  where (chunk, remainder) = splitAt l x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VczBCgIhEMbxu0/xHTpssC0sewiEgo49g8giZSg7yaJG29ObbpR0cvj9ZzQqTJoopYt5uMneXpxDKIndEeLs4mfIINl3AUJixCE/lcaC/7SgIU5hm3k1jl/y@q6su2oPCgxPo71Gs9a2tnIYZrLxFEFYWGIlZJy9dRGb@p3ou24vIYa2bweZ3g)

Now as an exercise you could try to solve this problem using a higher order function like `scanr,scanl,foldl,foldr` to avoid the explicit recursion.